# Use case of modifiable string literal

Tags: c++, c++11

For many years, this was deprecated:

```
char *p = "abc";
```

Then made illegal in C++11. However, many aren't aware that this is legal:

```
char *p = (char*)"abc";
```

The catch is:

> [C++11, diff.lex] Programs that have a legitimate reason to treat string literals as pointers to potentially modifiable memory are probably rare.

Is there a legitimate reason? Please focus your answer on hosted environments.

Comment: It should be noted that `char *p = (char*)"abc";` is legal, but modifying what `p` points to is still Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: And since many years best is `const char *p = "abc";`

Comment: @JacekCz For newly written programs yes. The recommendation to add a cast is for compatibility purposes.

Comment: Ah, I think I initially misunderstood what that quote was saying: *potentially modifiable* refers to something like `char* strchr(char*, int);`, where function does not reflect in its signature that it won't modify the string; or a function that could modify the string, but doesn't do it for the given set of arguments.

Comment: @user5443608 If "newly" we understand ab. 20 years ...  :) What mean "freestanding" in this context?

Comment: @dyp Interestingly enough that non-const overload was added by C++.

Comment: @user5443608 I don't think that's the case. C originally didn't have `const`, so one could claim the original version must have been the non-const one. Currently, C seems to contain the broken `char *strchr(const char *s, int c);` interface (probably for compatibility reasons).

Comment: @dyp [c.strings]/4 `The function signature strchr(const char*, int) shall be replaced by the two declarations: ...` Compare to C99: 7.21.5.2 `char *strchr(const char *s, int c);` But that change seems to be related to function overloading rather than the lack of const in ancient C.

Comment: Hmm C90 already introduced `const`, and had the `char* strchr(const char*, int);` version. However, prior to the introduction of `const`, if there was a `strchr` function, it must have been `char* strchar(char*, int);` (if there's been prototype checking at all).

Comment: @dyp It would be ironic that C99 fixed a bug reintroduced by C++ for a limitation in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an example of how old code might have leveraged mutable string literals, imagine myriad places in a state machine replacing a work queue a la `strtok("step-one|step-two|step-three|step-four", "|")`, with those being dequeued by `strtok(NULL, "|")` from a variety of functions.

Note that if the same call site - `strtok("step-one|step-two|step-three|step-four", "|")` - were executed again, a subsequent `strtok(NULL, "|")` call would immediately return `NULL`, because the first `strtok` call for that literal would have delimited it after the first token.

Getting identical behaviour from any replacement `strtok(str, delim)` function without mutable / unpooled string literals - using only C++ Standard functionality - seems pretty hard to me.

If this exact behaviour matched what the application needed, and the app was first written when modifiable literals weren't deprecated, then the developer may well have felt they had *"a legitimate reason to treat string literals as pointers to potentially modifiable memory"*, as it allowed the most concise and simple code with this peculiar behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

The rationale is that you could have a large legacy code base in which `char *` are passed around even for parameters that are only accessed for reading. Forcing conversion to `const char *` could ripple huge code changes for no real benefit (and in some case it can even force code duplication).

Note that the ability of casting to `(char *)` a `(const char *)` is not a special rule (you can always cast away constness of pointers and references and the code is legal if no actual write operation occurs when the pointed/referenced object was declared constant).

Note also that a `const char *` doesn't imply that the pointed char is constant (i.e. that it cannot be written to) but just that you are not allowed to do a write operation **using that pointer**... the pointed object can actually change if it's not constant and there are other ways to reach it (e.g. aliasing).

Const-ness of pointers and references is a property of the pointer/reference, not of the referenced object. Probably "const pointer" is a bad name for them indeed, and "read-only pointer" would have been more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

It's not particularly special. This is also legal:

```
const int x = 3;
int *ptr = (int *) &x;
```

Comment: I'm asking specifically about string literals, not `const` and undefined behavior in general.

Comment: "undefined" is ... undefined .... :) It is one of wonderful words in C/C++ Much coffee can drink during philosophical discussion

Answer (score 1):

Legacy code (we had quite some migrations from VC++6 exploiting this feature) and, more in general, code where you have functions that may modify their argument or not depending on other conditions, or that have underrestrictive conditions on their signature for other reasons (typically, compatibility with C, where overloading is not available).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there can still be around some *very* old piece of code (or less old piece of code written by uncautious programmer), mainly C code, where some routine can take a pointer to char, never modify the pointed array, but still omit the `const` modifier in signature.

If you want to avoid the `const_cast` to remove constness a lazy workaroud is to directly declare the string litteral as `char *` instead of `const char *`, **provided the programmer ensures it will never be modified**. Here that only means that since the compiler can no longer notice a modification attempt on a potentially unmodifiable string, the programmer must do it himself.

It may not even bore old programmers, used to the early times of K&R C (const did not exist), or to assembly language, but it is bad, because it will confuse future maintainers.

My opinion is that this was acceptable some years or decades ago, when a lot of third party code did not use `const` in signature, and consistently repeating `const_cast` was really boring, but I now do agree with the quote: I cannot imagine a legitimate reason to currently write `char * p = "abc";`, not (vade retro satanas) `char * p = (char *) "abc";`